# Removing duplicate element from a linked list- Java

Tags: java, linked-list

## EDIT

I decided to use a HashSet instead as it has is O(N). However, I am still having an issue that it's not deleting all repeating numbers, 10 13 11 11 12 11 10 12 11.
It returns : 10 13 11 12 10 11

```
static void removeDups(Node node) {
        HashSet<Integer> values = new HashSet<Integer>();
        Node previous = null;
        while(node != null) {
            if(values.contains(node.data)) 
                previous.next = node.next;
            else
                values.add(node.data);
                previous = node;

                node= node.next;

    }
    }
```

## Irrelevant

I am trying to remove duplicate elements from a linked list but for some reason, It does not remove the last repeating element. For instance if the list is 10,11,12,11,12,9,11, It returns : 10,11,12,9,11.

```
     public static void removeDups1(Node head){
        if(head == head.next)
            head = head.next.next;
        Node fastptr =head;
        Node slowptr = head;
        while(slowptr.next != null && fastptr.next.next !=null) {
            if(slowptr.data == fastptr.data) {
                fastptr.next = fastptr.next.next;}

            slowptr = slowptr.next;
            fastptr = fastptr.next;

   }}
```

Comment: What the is that first `if` for?  Why would the first element be pointing to itself?

Comment: i would expect a doubly nested while loop. your implementation doesn't seem close in the first place.

Comment: You should be comparing objects with `.equals()`.  `slowptr.data == fastptr.data` should be `slowptr.data.equals(fastptr.data)`.

Comment: Wrong in algorithm, for each element in node, you have to check all elements after it, you need double nested loop.

Comment: Sorry I think the algorithm without that error would still be flawed as you move slowptr in every step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is trying to find if there are any duplicates for each element from the current position to the next two positions in the linked list. But duplicates can occur anywhere in the linked list. Therefore, for each element, it should traverse through the linked list once again.

That would be a O(n^2) solution

A better approach would be to maintain a hash to keep track of already visited data.

This would be a O(n) solution.

Answer (score 1):

Checking `fastptr.next.next == null` prematurely exits your loop.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I wasn't sure if that was what was happening

Answer (score 0):

I think, since at the beginning you are pointing both `fastptr` and `slowptr` to the same Node, and always end up pointing them to the same node at the end of the while, you're always comparing the same Nodes here, doing nothing valuable to the algorithm:

```
 if(slowptr.data == fastptr.data)
```

Anyways, the algorightm's logic seems all wrong.

Like others sayd, you should do two loops, one inside another: the first one to the slowptr, the second one to the fastptr

Try to implement based on this proposition:

**For all Node (pointed by slowptr, first loop), for all subsequent nodes (second loop) do see if they are the same.**

Answer (score 0):

I don't see real Java when I look to your code. But anyway as @Aishwarya said a better solution is to build a map or hash set for better performance. Using Java built-in functions it is even simpler. Just do:

```
LinkedList<Node> yourList = ...
LinkedList<Node> filteredList = new LinkedList<>(new HashSet<Node>(yourList));
```

To make this work properly you must make sure that `Node` `equals(Object o)` and `hashCode()`are correctly implemented.

Then your (generic) duplicate removal function might be:

```
public static void removeDups(LinkedList pList) {
    return new LinkedList(new HashSet(pList));   
    // indeed specifying <Node> is not really needed
}
```